Avoid floating point error when importing mixed alphanumeric / numeric data from Excel into R
I have an Excel file with a column of alphanumeric codes of variable length - see sample at end of question. I have been trying to read this into R using the readxl library:
read_xlsx("File.xlsx")
This works for over 90% of the data, but for a significant minority of data points, I'm getting a floating point error, e.g. 2.2000000000000002 or 8.1999999999999993.
This only occurs for codes in the format "number point number", i.e. not for stand alone numbers (2 or 8) or for codes including letters (2.4.a or 5.2.b.i).
I have selected the entire column in Excel and formatted as Text, but without improving the situation. I have also tried using a different R library to read in the data: openxlsx's read.xlsx function, but the same error occurs. This suggests the error is in how Excel is saving the file (treating decimal codes as numeric, even though I have set the whole column to text), rather than an error with R. R is successfully reading the column in as character (<chr>).
Sample data



In original .xlsx file
Read in by R as




1
1


1.1
1.1000000000000001


1.2
1.2


1.3
1.3


2
2


2.1
2.1


2.2
2.2000000000000002


2.3
2.2999999999999998


2.4
2.4


2.5
2.5


3
3


3.1
3.1


3.1.a
3.1.a


3.1.b
3.1.b


3.1.c
3.1.c


3.1.d
3.1.d


3.2
3.2


3.3
3.3


3.3.a
3.3.a


3.3.b
3.3.b


3.4
3.4


4
4


4.1
4.0999999999999996


4.1.a
4.1.a


4.1.b
4.1.b




Is the first number coming out as 1.1000000000000001 or 1.0000000000000001? To Import them as text you can use col_types, e.g. col_types="text".

With readxl::read_xlsx argument col_types you can set that column to numeric and the error should go away.

Also, try x <- c(2.2000000000000002, 2.2999999999999998, 4.0999999999999996);print(x, digits = 20L);print(round(x, 1), digits = 20L) and see that those numbers probably do not have the decimals you think they have.

Thanks @AndreWildberg - the first part of your comment was my mistake, which I've now corrected. I'll try setting col_types to text, but R is already reading this column in as , so I'm not sure if this will affect the output?

Thanks @RuiBarradas. I will try setting col_types to numeric, but think it would probably result in an error, as not all of the column can be represented numerically (e.g. 4.2.b)

Yes, just to confirm, setting col_types to "text" has no effect. Setting col_types to "numeric" does read in the numbers correctly, but leaves all codes which contained alphabetical characters (e.g. 4.2.a) as NA. The round() function doesn't work on the data, as it is a character vector.

'setting col_types to "text" has no effect' - does it mean R still reads this column as numbers?

Much as we like questions to be self-contained, it might be useful to link to a sample Excel file here ...

I replicated your issue and the only thing I tried that worked was to first convert your .xlsx to .csv, then use read.csv().

I'm not an Excel expert and I know less about R, but I believe when you select Text format for a cell or column in Excel, you're affecting only how data is displayed, not how it's stored.  If you type "1.1" into a cell, Excel is going to represent it internally as a floating-point number, just about no matter what — and that's how the value is going to be stored in the .xlsx file, as well.  And then  when R reads that file, it is (unfortunately for you) reasonable for it to say, "this cell is a number, so I'll treat it as a number".

As @rotabor suggests in an answer, one way — the only way I know of — to force Excel to store a cell's value as a string is to prefix it with ' when you first type it in.  (I can understand that may not be an option for you, though.)

Such style "1.1" is problematic since it can be accepted by a number or a date. It can be resolved by putting the apostrophe sign at the start of the string: "'1.1". This enforces Excel to treat the entered text as a text. Potentially this can solve the problem. Otherwise put any letter at the start of the string: "R1.1". Considering its meaning it should not affect anything, but codes will not be parsed as numbers.
UPD
The better way I guess is to replace the comma by, for e. g., the Middle Dot (0x00B7): "1·1"

It's better to avoid the problem then cope with its consequences.

Here is a solution.
Write a function that

tries to coerce the values to numeric;
If some cannot be coerced, they become NA;
assign the new values based on the corresponding elements of the input vector.

library(readxl)

round_char <- function(x) {
  y <- as.numeric(x)
  i <- is.na(y)
  y[i] <- x[i]
  y
}

df1 <- read_xlsx("~/Temp/so_79134563.xlsx", col_types = c("text", "text"))

round_char(df1$read_xlsx)
#> Warning in round_char(df1$read_xlsx): NAs introduced by coercion
#>  [1] "1"     "1.1"   "1.2"   "1.3"   "2"     "2.1"   "2.2"   "2.3"   "2.4"  
#> [10] "2.5"   "3"     "3.1"   "3.1.a" "3.1.b" "3.1.c" "3.1.d" "3.2"   "3.3"  
#> [19] "3.3.a" "3.3.b" "3.4"   "4"     "4.1"   "4.1.a" "4.1.b"

df1$rounded <- round_char(df1$read_xlsx)
#> Warning in round_char(df1$read_xlsx): NAs introduced by coercion
df1
#> # A tibble: 25 × 3
#>    Original read_xlsx          rounded
#>    <chr>    <chr>              <chr>  
#>  1 1        1                  1      
#>  2 1.1      1.1000000000000001 1.1    
#>  3 1.2      1.2                1.2    
#>  4 1.3      1.3                1.3    
#>  5 2        2                  2      
#>  6 2.1      2.1                2.1    
#>  7 2.2      2.2000000000000002 2.2    
#>  8 2.3      2.2999999999999998 2.3    
#>  9 2.4      2.4                2.4    
#> 10 2.5      2.5                2.5    
#> # ℹ 15 more rows

Created on 2024-10-28 with reprex v2.1.1
